# With square matrices, prove by mathematical induction that $(ABA^{-1})^k=AB^kA^{-1}$

Tags: matrices, proof-verification, induction

Assume that matrix $A$ and $B$ are square with same dimensions.

prove by mathematical induction that $(ABA^{-1})^k=AB^kA^{-1}$

if I let $k=2$ then I *think* I can do

$$
(ABA^{-1})^k=AB^kA^{-1}\\
(ABA^{-1})^2=AB^2A^{-1}\\
(ABA^{-1})(ABA^{-1})=ABBA^{-1}\\
ABBA^{-1}=ABBA^{-1}\\
$$

From here I can see a repeating pattern where I can manually make $k$ any positive integer and do the above but I'm not sure how to do this formally for the general case.

Comment: Just do the induction step from $k\mapsto k+1$. You have almost done it. Try it yourself now. Don't ask others, because then you will not make progress.

Comment: In fact you really don't need induction for this. But if you wish, do: First suppose for $k\in\mathbb{N}$, $(ABA^{-1})^k=AB^kA^{-1}$ is true. This is your inductive hypothesis. Secondly proceed to $k+1$. Finally by the principle of induction, the proposition is true for $k\in\mathbb{N}\ge2$.

Comment: @poyea I'd like to see you try to write a proof that does not involve induction or "$\dots$". Also, in your sketch of an inductive proof, you are missing the initialization step.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Yes, I didn't write the base case because OP's done that. And in quest of a *mathematically formal* proof, I admit one can only use induction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have already formed a basis for induction.

Assuming that $n=k$ is true, we have $$(ABA^{-1})^k=AB^kA^{-1}.$$ Hence if we consider $n=k+1$, we get $$(ABA^{-1})^{k+1}=(ABA^{-1})^kABA^{-1}=AB^kA^{-1}ABA^{-1}=AB^{k+1}A^{-1}$$ which completes the induction step.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

The inductive set is

*Inductive hypothesis*: for some $k\ge2$, $(ABA^{-1})^k=AB^kA^{-1}$ is true.

You then have to prove that  $\;(ABA^{-1})^{k+1}=AB^{k+1}A^{-1}$ is true.

Just write $$(ABA^{-1})^{k+1}=(ABA^{-1})^k(ABA^{-1}),$$ 
use the inductive hypothesis and play with associativity of multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

Base case: $k = 1$

$(ABA^{-1})^1 = AB^1A^{-1}$

Hypothesis: Suppose for some $k, (ABA^{-1})^k = AB^kA^{-1}$

Inductive step: We must show that $(ABA^{-1})^{k+1} = AB^{k+1}A^{-1}$

$(ABA^{-1})^{k+1}\\
(ABA^{-1})^{k}(ABA^{-1})\\
(AB^{k}A^{-1})(ABA^{-1}) \text { by the inductive hypothesis}\\
AB^{k}BA^{-1}\\
AB^{k+1}A^{-1}\\
$